# Use select query for the time as of in SQL Server temporal table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a temporal table in my database which allows me to do things like:

```
select * 
from tableName as of '01-nov-2019'
```

I can also do this:

```
declare @dateToView dateTime

select @dateToView = top 1 dateColumn 
from tableHoldingDates

select * 
from tableName as of @dateToView
```

However, I'm rewriting a View, which uses temporal tables but cannot declare variables.

I'd like to try to write something like:

```
select * 
from tableName as of (top 1 dateColumn from tableHoldingDates)
```

But cannot. Does anyone know whether it's possible to use a select for the 'as of' of the temporal tables?

Comment: Views cannot be parametrised. You would have to either hard code the value for `AS OF` in the `VIEW`, or define it when you query the `VIEW`.

Comment: There are some examples of this in [Temporal Table Usage Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-usage-scenarios?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Possibly related to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166973/join-for-system-time-with-column-as-the-effective-system-time